# How to solve longest already present substring in O(n)?

Tags: string, automata, suffix-tree, suffix-array

Given a string **a** I need to find for every position **i** in **a** the length of the longest substring **b** such that it starts in position **i** and was already present in **a**, which means that there exists **i'<i** such that a[i...i+len(b)] = b = a[i'...i'+len(b)].
For example, for a="ababaab" the answer is [0,0,3,2,1,2,1].
I need an algorithm that will solve this problem in O(|a|) or O(|a|log|a|).

I think this problem could be solved with suffix automaton. We can calculate for every state **s** in automaton the first position in string where the substring that corresponds to the state ends. With this information we will solve the problem in O(n^2) with just walking on the automaton from the starting position **i** while first_pos - size < i. But I can't find a way to optimise this solution.